# Did the Enterprise have a janitor?

Tags: star-trek

I've always wondered who vacuumed the corridors or did other cleaning/housekeeping kinds of duties in common areas of the Enterprise or other Galaxy-class/large ships. Especially in TNG, the ship has civilians providing services for the crew, such as a bartender and a barber. So is there any canon references of having a janitor or other civilians providing services like this?

Comment: I vaguely remembering someone quipping the ship cleaned itself

Comment: Bartender and hairdresser offer a direct service to humans (and other races), so it's normal there are on board.

Comment: Robert Heinlein solved the housekeeping problem in "The Door Into Summer".

Answer (score 1):

The references to [janitor](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Janitor) imply there are such people, however, on board the ship it would involve a much more sophisticated level of activity. Robots would be used to do the grunt work and the "janitor" would have to take care of the artificial gravity, the air recyclers, the food processors, the waste recyclers, etc. Because Enterprise is a closed system, the "janitoreal" crew would work at a level equivalent to engineering and the "chief janitor" would be on a level equivalent to Geordi.

Comment: I think this would basically be the equivalent of the First Lieutenant in the modern US Navy. Navy folks, check me on that?